# Have a class access another class that has been defined after that first class?

Tags: php, class

In PHP, is it at all possible to have a class access another class, that has been defined later in the code?

```
require_once class_common_functions.php
require_once class_display_page.php
require_once class_specific_functions.php
require_once class_parse_data.php
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, `class_display_page -> class_common_functions -> class_parse_data -> class_specific_functions`.

I could reorder these four,

```
require_once class_specific_functions.php
require_once class_parse_data.php
require_once class_common_functions.php
require_once class_display_page.php
```

But then I would like `class_specific_functions` and `class_parse_data` to have access to `class_common_functions` as well.

I'm not too sure how to do this? Any suggestions? I'm currently accessing classes from classes using the class contructor, but for that to work the classes have to be in a certain order.

I'm probably approaching this wrong. I'm used to developing simpler web sites, trying to learn.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using an autoloader and getting rid of all those `require_once` statements (or most of them, really).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a class access another class, that has been defined later in the code (assuming later to be code that's loaded later).  To use a class (access it's static methods/properties or instantiate it), the class file  must be loaded before trying to use it.  You get around having to micro-manage this  by using autoloading.

However, within the same file you define a class later in the file and access it at the begining

Here is an overview of autoloading: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php